# phonegap file plugin: how to implement file security

Tags: android, cordova, encryption, phonegap-plugins

I am developing native application targeting android mobiles using Sencha Touch and phonegap. In this app, I am using file plugin to read / write data. These files should be accessible only via this app not via other app and not via USB.

It should be either hidden or encrypted.

Question: How to implement this file security and encryption & decryption or Is there a plugin to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store only limited text information(upto 5Mb,temporary storage) you use webstorage with AES encryption using **CryptoJS** library to encrypt/decrypt the data. [Refer this link for CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#AES)

 **OR** 
If you want it in native way, you can use AES-256 file encryption with password based key(otherwise reverse engineering can break your encryption) Refer [this Q&A for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992019/java-256-bit-aes-password-based-encryption) AES encryption/decryption .  Since in android java doesnot support AES-256 you need to add Spongy castle (http://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/) otherwise use AES-128 algorithm. 
Spring frame for android also provides an abstracted **org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.AndroidEncryptors** class for text encryption.

Comment: This is a question, can we encrypt the data using CryptoJS and then store it on the device file system rather than using Spongy castle

Comment: I think it can be done(I have no hands on experience in that) because cordova provides File Management API for android. Please refer documentation: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File.